# Resolving async function within internal callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

When explicitly returning a `new Promise` from a function we get `resolve` and `reject` functions passed in. We can use these methods inside our function at any point to indicate the resolution or rejection of the promise, including inside callbacks to other functions internally.

Consider:

```
const doSomeDbWork = function (db) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     db.doStuff(result => resolve(result));
   });
};
```

Is there an equivalent when using `async` without explicitly returning a `new Promise` when we can't also await (like in the case of this db callback)?

```
const doSomeDbWork = async function (db) {
  db.doStuff(result => /* ? */);
};
```

I'm currently thinking that this isn't possible and that I just need to return a new Promise. Have I missed a trick? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `var result = await promisify(db.doStuff)`

Comment: @elclanrs - probably meant `var result = await promisify(db.doStuff)()`, right?

Comment: @Amit, ah yes, that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent when using `async` without explicitly returning a `new Promise`.

No. `async`/`await` only works with promises (or thenables), and you have to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) everything else *yourself*. In your case, that would most likely be something like

```
async function doSomeDbWork(db) {
    return new Promise(db.doStuff);
}
```

or

```
async function doSomeDbWork(db) {
     return new Promise(resolve => { db.doStuff(resolve); });
}
```

(possible with an `await` after the `return`).